Is it correct to refer to a group (3rd) and transition to 2nd person in a paragraph
I'm writing a business document.  Is it ok to introduce a concept in the 3rd person and then transition to 2nd person to be more personable?  For example:
"Full-time employees may take up to 6 weeks of vacation.  You must request vacation time in advance using the timekeeping application."
Am I overthinking it or is that ok?  Perhaps I'm overly conscious of it because we were writing all documents strictly in 3rd person.

That's certainly possible. There is nothing grammatically or stylistically wrong with that transition. The question is: Does the document provide instructions to a user or does it document a procedure for the administrators?
If the text is meant to guide a user, it is today more common to write it in second person (e.g. the US government's guide to taxes: "Find out if you need to file a federal tax return ..." or Chase instructions on how to open a bank account: "Open a checking account online with the coupon code or enter your email address to get your coupon and bring it to a Chase Branch to open an account."). If the text is meant to provide guidance to those maintaining the procedure, it is usually written in third person (e.g. technical documentation for software programmers describing what users can do).
So, if your document is meant to inform full-time employees of the rules surrounding vacations:

As a full-time employee you may take up to 6 weeks of vacation. You must request vacation time in advance using the timekeeping application.

If the document is meant to inform the human resources department or the company's administration of those rules:

Full-time employees may take up to 6 weeks of vacation. They must request vacation time in advance using the timekeeping application.


Can you say how it matters whether the document provides instructions to a user or documents a procedure for the administrators?

@RobbieGoodwin When the document provides instructions to a user, you address them ("you"). When the document documents a procedure, you talk about the elements of the procedure ("they").

Interesting idea, Ben, and where is that prescribed, please?

I suggest that's not OK, for two-and-a-half reasons.
The 'half' a reason is grammatical, because I've never actually heard it said that paragraphs must maintain tense and person in as strict a way as sentences.
Despite that, when I asked my search engine 'What defines a paragraph' most offerings at least came close to Merriam-Webster's in that it …deals with one point or gives the words of one speaker… Not rigidly but nevertheless, that to me suggests any transition between persons or perspectives is at least stretching the point.
More clearly I don't think it matters whether this is a 'business' document or any other kind - whatever type of 'business document' is meant here. What does matter is that any document should maintain a consistent style on all levels including, here, persons or perspectives.
Above that general rule about style stands the particular comment '… because we were writing all documents strictly in 3rd person…', implying the writer is supposed to be following house rules which, being unstated, serve largely to muddy the waters. The clear exception is that all documents like the subject are clearly designed to be written as stated, '… strictly in 3rd person…'
